# typing npm (followed by anything does nothing)

Tags: npm

So just recently on my ubuntu 14.04 command line, I decided to type

`sudo npm install -g npm`

Because I got a warning to upgrade npm by doing so.  After doing this, I got some messages that the upgrade was successful, and that it's at version 3 point something, but I don't know how to confirm this now.

But now when I run any npm commands, nothing happens at all!  If I type

`npm install -g generator-meanjs`

I just go to the next command line in bash as if nothing happened.  I can type

`npm i love eating pizza and drinking water squirrels beside me`

Also yields the same result. I was expecting some kind of error message.

What went wrong with my npm and how do I fix it?

Comment: did you try nuking everything and starting over? ie. `sudo npm uninstall npm -g` and running `udo npm install -g npm` again?

Comment: Yes.  Doing the `sudo npm uninstall -g npm` does nothing because any arguments after npm simply does nothing.  I also did `sudo apt-get --purge remove npm` then `sudo apt-get install npm`.  But the results are the same, npm remains unresponsive. This in turn has also broken my `nvm` and I can't seem to run node applications because of dependency on npm.  Any other ideas?

Comment: This is my only other thought: do you by chance have any aliases in your `.bash_profile` or  `.bashrc`? Perhaps there is a conflict somewhere.

Comment: I didn't see anything relevant in those files. However I found some files called npm in folders like /usr/local/bin/npm and I manually deleted those after the `sudo apt-get --purge remove npm`.  Then I re-installed the npm, and now it seems a bit responsive again.  Just installing stuff via npm to see if everything has resolved itself.

Comment: Cool glad you got it working.  Sounds like maybe there was a broken symlink or something.